# Inkscape SVG transform

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am trying to open an svg file with Inkscape. The svg elements have transform properties. Any browser can display the image withut a problem. However, when Inkscape opens the image,all the element transforms are ignored and the elements are all drawn in one position.

Can someone suggest how I can force Inkscape to consider the transforms?

Comment: I would find curious that Inkscape support `transform` but needs an option to read correctly transformed figures. My guess is that Inkscape doesn’t support this SVG1.1 property and we have to wait for someone to implement it.

Comment: Could you link to an example file to demonstrate the problem? Inkscape does support SVG transforms in principle, so it's probably a problem specific to your file.

Comment: Also, what version of Inkscape are you using?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Here is a sample svg excerpt which displays correctly on Mozilla but not with inkscape. The black line should be at the right and not at the left.

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g style="transform: translate3d(-33px, 0px, 0px);"><path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" d="M177 48l0 96"></path></g><g style="transform: translate3d(-129px, 0px, 0px);"><path stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" d="M177 48 l96 0"></path></g></svg>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax does work with Inkscape 1.0.2:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g transform="translate(-33, 0)">
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" d="M177 48l0 96">
    </path>
</g>
<g transform="translate(-129, 0)">
    <path stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" d="M177 48 l96 0">
    </path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Note that this corresponds to what I find in [the W3C website](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)

Comment: Any idea why the code in my comment does not work? These code snippets are being generated by a complex process and it won't be easy to change the output so it is our first priority to see if it can be fixed with the right version of Inkscape or patch or something similar. Thanks.

Comment: It seems Inkscape observes only some of the CSS `style` properties. I'm curious how it could be overwhelmingly complicated to change the syntax in the output of your code.

Comment: What I have here is just a simple example. We are generating svg images on the fly. They are generated by one piece of code in advance and then transformed by another piece later. Now we have to figure out the positions and draw the objects later so that Inkscape can interpret it correctly. It involves changing some third party code which is always a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry can't help more - all I can say is that I don't know whether these CSS style properties are part of the SVG standard. If they are, blame Inkscape for not implementing them, if they aren't, blame that 3rd party code for not observing them.

Comment: The third party cannot be blamed as like I have mentioned, it all works well with browsers. Inkscape is being considered to extend the scope of the project. No point in blaming anyone, we are just going to change the third party code to generate output compatible with browsers as well as Inkscape. Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem - remember to accept answer if you feel this is appropriate.